# How to run multiple queries in a KSH script

Tags: email, ksh, sql

I have a KSH script that has one SQL Query and generates and emails output of the query in HTML format. I want to change the script so that it has three SQL queries and the last query generates and emails the HTML output page of just that query.

So far I have:

- Query 1 - Creates a table by performing a select into into a table in tempdb
- Query 2 - Creates a table by performing a select into into a table in tempdb
- Query 3 - Performs a join between table 1 and table 2  and creates
  table 3 
           Then table 3 is queried and and the result is placed in a HTML file and emailed

Comment: There's no need to post a script that long, unless you believe its in error.

Comment: @tango29, a good guide to asking good questions is here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: If you want people to review your code: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/